# Why did NASA release Perseverance (rover) videos with a stop motion effect?

Tags: perseverance, mars2020

This is the video released by Perseverance (rover):

[image]

Why did NASA release Perseverance (rover) videos with a stop motion effect?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This animated gif is comprised of images that were acquired by the Navigation Camera (Navcam) located on the rover mast, part of the Mastcam-Z instrument. Mastcam-Z is capable of acquiring videos (generally at about 4 frames per second), but sending this data back to Earth could take a long time.

To send data to Earth, the rover transmits a signal to a Martian orbiter (usually the Mars Reconnaissance Orbiter, Mars Odyssey, Trace Gas Orbiter, or Maven), which then relays the data back to Earth via the Deep Space Network. The data rate for each transmission is on the order of 2 megabits per second - and transmission may only occur a few times a day. A video of the rover wheel motion (rather than a series of a few images) would have required more bandwidth, which may have delayed other high priority data products from making it to Earth in a timely manner.

For this particular wheel-checkout test, collecting a few images of the wheels, rather than a video, must have been sufficient to ensure that the system was working.

Sources:

[Image source](https://mars.nasa.gov/resources/25704/multiple-views-of-perseverances-wheels-wiggling/)

[Mars 2020 Rover Communication Information](https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/spacecraft/rover/communications/)

Comment: In other words: the purpose of the test was to see if the wheels move. You can clearly see that they do. What would more frames of video tell you that you don't already know?

Comment: Was video even required for the test? I would imagine they have wheel position telemetry.

Comment: @OrganicMarble How do you know the wheel itself is moving and not the linkage with the wheel having broken? Telemetry from a position indicator doesn't tell you that. Having visual indication gives you that bit more confidence something unexpected hasn't happened.

Comment: @user1937198 do you have detailed knowledge of how the wheel position transducers work?

Comment: @OrganicMarble No, just speculation from someone thinking about the risks that might have caused them to do it.

Comment: I would imagine after this test they'd just trust the telemetry, but I could see this as being a cross-check that what the telemetry is telling them matches what is happening, as well as that the wheel rotates correctly.

Comment: They also have a public engagement mission to fulfill, all. These missions happen if and when there is public support for them, since after all they are funded by taxpayers. Video may not be strictly required, but if you want to show someone what their tax dollars are doing, a plot or picture won't catch their imaginations like video would. Sure, you'll carry on that mission and do your science even if you don't engage the public, but then good luck asking for tax dollars the next go-around. It pays to engage the public and to spark their imaginations is what I'm saying.

Comment: That said, this is a critical time in that mission and they likely have lots of priorities beside engaging the public plus tight constraints on resources, so my guess is that a very low frame-rate video is all they could manage to transmit without unduly interfering with higher priorities at the time.

Comment: They must have lots of metrics to cross-check to remove all doubt as to what's happening. If wheel steering angle is changing *and* wheel steering torque is changing and power consumption is up during the change, and if the rover logic shows a high-level command for steering and if the appropriate actuators/motors show a low-level command to turn for steering... then you can say very confidently without seeing a picture that in fact the wheels have been steered. What the pictures do that metrics won't is show the wheel in the context of its environment to help catch or confirm the unexpected.

Comment: Why there is no trail made by the wheel in the soil?